# Vertical merge identical cells between page breaks

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to vertically merge cells in Excel in column A between already set page breaks (i.e. prevent merging over page breaks).  I have code that tells the row where page breaks are located, and code to merge cells in Range column A, if two or more adjacent cells are identical (code shown below), now I am trying to figure out how to combine the two code snippets (code shown below) to only merge identical cells on full pages and not across the already set page breaks.  Can anyone come up with a solution?  Many thanks in advance.

**Code to find row number of existing page breaks:**

```
Sub PageBreakAddresses() 'this finds row of pagebreak
    Dim pb As HPageBreak

    For Each pb In Sheet1.HPageBreaks
        MsgBox pb.Location.row - 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**Code to merge identical cells in column A:**

```
Sub MergeCells()  ' this merges identical cells in column A

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set rngMerge = Range("A1:A" & i)

MergeAgain:
    For Each cell In rngMerge
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            GoTo MergeAgain
        End If
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: After run your  code MergeCells, run  mycode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merge cells, execute this code.

```
Sub ResetHPage()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngST As Range, rngEnd As Range
    Dim vHrow()
    Dim C As Integer, n As Long, k As Long, i As Long
    Dim mergeValue

    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview


    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    C = WS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    n = WS.HPageBreaks.Count

    For i = 1 To n
        k = k + 1
        ReDim Preserve vHrow(1 To k)
        vHrow(k) = WS.HPageBreaks(k).Location.Row
    Next i
    For i = 1 To n
        For Each rng In Range("a" & vHrow(i), Cells(vHrow(i), C))
            If rng.MergeCells Then
                With rng.MergeArea
                    If rng.Address = .Range("a1").Address Then
                    Else
                        mergeValue = .Range("a1")

                        Set rngST = .Range("a1")
                        Set rngEnd = rng.MergeArea(.Rows.Count)

                        .UnMerge
                        rng = mergeValue
                        Range(rngST, rng.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
                        Range(rng, rngEnd).Merge
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next rng
    Next i

    WS.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Dy Lee. I did a small test run on the code you provide thus far and it appears to do what I want it to do! I did commented-out the second to last line `WS.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous` because I did not need the border lines to be drawn. I need to test it out more depth on my full report over the next few days, to see what it does overall. But thus far, very good!  Thank you!.  If you have a moment, could you please document your code so that I can understand better what it is doing, and when it is doing it? I want to modify it a bit to center merge the txt.

Comment: Colums (1).horizontalalignment=xlcenter

Comment: Thanks for `Colums (1).horizontalalignment=xlcenter` tip.  I hope to have more time to test out and study your code further tomorrow.  Thus far, it looks and works great!  Thanks!

Comment: The code above has been tested and works perfectly in my case.  Thank you, Dy Lee!